# $ix+y-z=0\\iy+z=0$ basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the dimension over $\mathbb{C}$ of the space of solutions of the following systems of equations. Also find a basis for this space of solutions.
>
> $ix+y-z=0\\iy+z=0$

Using the formula $\text{row rank}+\dim \text{space of solutions}=n$, in which n is the number of variables.

I figured out that $\dim \text{space of solutions}=1$

However I cannot find the basis.

**Questions**:

What is the basis of solutions of this system of equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the so called "space of solutions" has the dimension $1$, any element in the space forms a basis for the space because the solutions of this system of equations represents a line, and any point in a line can be written as a linear combination of another line.

**Edit:**

From the equation 2, $-iy = z$, and substitute this into $Eq.1$, you will get a line equation. the points on which will be your solutions.
For example $(1,\frac{1}{i-1}, \frac{1}{i+1})$

Comment: What is the basis?

Comment: @PedroGomes choose any solution of this system of equations, that will be your basis.Note that, since the dimension of the space of solutions is $1$, your basis will contain only one element.

Comment: My problem is to find one of those solutions.

Comment: Then you shouldn't not ask your question as to find the basis, but rather how to solve the given system of equations.

Comment: I want to find a basis.

Comment: @PedroGomes I have edited my answer, see the edit.

Comment: $(-\frac{1}{i}-1,1,-i)$ another basis. I was doing silly mistakes when solving the system. Anyway, you checked my procedures to be right!